# Can FileHelpers extract different records from within the same file

Tags: header, filehelpers

I have a lot of files having header and trailer. These records are different from the body of the files,  for example:

```
(BOF)
Header    20180821         12345(CRLF)
A   12  BCAD   000012345          20160324     XYZ(CRLF)
B   10  BCXD   000012331          20160324     ABC(CRLF)
C   99  BCZZ   000010845          20160324     1AB(CRLF)
Trailer          003  00000(CRLF)
(EOF)
```

I know FH can "IgnoreFirst", "IgnoreLast", but my question is can it extract or convert those headers/trailers to a different object that is different from the main body?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MultiRecordEngine`. Documentation is [here](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/).

```
var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(
    typeof(HeaderObject),
    typeof(RecordObject),
    typeof(TrailerObject));

engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(CustomSelector);
```

and then define a `CustomSelector`.

```
private Type CustomSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
{
    if (recordLine.Length == 0)
        return null;

    if (recordLine.StartsWith("Header")))
        return typeof(HeaderObject);
    else if (recordLine.StartsWith("Trailer")))
        return typeof(TrailerObject);
    // else
    return typeof(RecordObject);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your suggestions. I'll try this. Thanks again.